# Unkown token in my wallet

Tags: erc-20, security, phishing

I received a transaction to my ETH wallet containing a token I don't recognize. It's clearly a phishing attempt trying to lure me into a website, however, the transaction seems to contain an smart contract.

Besides not following the link and not interacting with said token, do I need to do something else to protect my funds/other valid tokens?

Here's the token:
https://etherscan.io/token/0xdc09ef6ba2a135b350d3d05c409497485d8b0a00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smart contract directly can not do nothing in your wallet unless you interact with it using some external website given by them or redirected by any link.

What smart contracts can not do?

1. They can not take any ETH from your wallet
2. They can not take any tokens like USDT, BUSD, DAI etc.

You need to avoid such tokens and let it remain in your wallet (it is not visible in your wallet app but only in blockchain)

So, no need to worry, most important thing is that you should avaoid clicking any website link or buttons which you do not have any knowledge of.

Answer (score 1):

> Besides not following the link and not interacting with said token, do
> I need to do something else to protect my funds/other valid tokens?

You are safe if not interact to token, these tokens have no comercial value (usually are scams, maybe some advertising of something), do not get interest in sell then. If you use metamask and this token is appearing for you, i sugest you to ocult the token in the wallet, click in the token, in the hamburguer menu in the right upper corner and in "ocult tokenName".